# Cloudcontrol user roles

Tags: roles, worker, cloudcontrol

How can I authorize a new user to perform only selected tasks. In my spcial case I'd like to have a user who has more rights than "ReadOnly" but less than the next role "Admin", so the user can create workers. I need an user who can perform some tasks but isn't able to delete the app.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is only the role-model for user-permissions on cloudControl. So no way to define the permissions more specific.

But another way to prevent a user from deleting the app is adding the user to a specific deployment, not the app. Of course when you add him to the live-deployment the user can delete this one.